# Why does Image not appear when rendering it before?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bitmap, windows-phone-7.1

Starting with a newly created project I add a button to my main page and do the following in the click handler:

I create an `Image` and assign a `BitmapImage` as its `Source`. Then I add the `Image` to my `LayoutRoot`. My expectation is that I see the image in the GUI after I click the button.

Now there is the twist: I also want to render this `Image` to a `WriteableBitmap`. Therefore I create such a bitmap and call its `Render` method to render the image.

Here is the problem: when I comment out the `Render` call then I immediately see the `Image` appear on my main page. When I include the `Render` call, then the Image appears not on the *first* button click, but on the *second*. Why?

Here is the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(62, 62);
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Image img = new Image() { Width = 62, Height = 62, Source = bmp };

        wbmp.Render(img, null); // <------ this line makes the difference

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 private Image _img = new Image ();
    public Image img
    {
        get
        {
            return _img;
        }
    }
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String PropertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(62, 62);
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative));
    Image img = new Image() { Width = 62, Height = 62, Source = bmp };

    wbmp.Render(img, null); // <------ this line makes the difference

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);

      NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
}
```

this should work.. try once...

Comment: Then try using INotifyPropertyChange.. probably the image has been updated but its not seen because the UI has not been notified that there has been a change.. and hence the update appears only during the second click..

Answer (score 0):

There are some [remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of using Render (may be one of these makes your issue):

> After calling this method, you must call Invalidate in order to render
>   the bitmap.
>
> This method does support UIElement objects that are not part of the
>   visual tree. You are required to call Measure and Arrange for
>   UIElement objects that are not in the visual tree, before calling
>   Render.

Comment: You are right, I didn't follow these remarks. But these are about the functioning of `Render` and shouldn't affect the following adding to the visual tree, right? I am not interested in the result of `Render` at this point. It's just that the call seems to have a side effect on the following `Add(img)` call. And I also tried to add `Measure` and `Arrange` before the render call and adding `Invalidate` after it. No change in behavior.